# How Can I Recreate Ubuntu Mini Remix?

Tags: custom-distributions

Minibuntu/Ubuntu Mini Remix was a fully working Ubuntu livecd containing only the minimal set of software to make the system work.

It is different from the [minimal cd](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mini-remix/+faq/2564) and is also different from [ubuntu core](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mini-remix/+faq/2565).

However, the main home page is down and there is no source on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-mini-remix).
I would like to recreate it to use as a base for remastering other isos.

The package list is [allegedly here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mini-remix/+faq/33).

Should I start from a normal iso and try to remove packages using the [instructions here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization)?

I want to get to the point of having a script that takes an iso, creates the chroot, unpacks, removes packages and spits out a minimal livecd.

Are there any scripts I can use as a base?

Things like [customizer](https://github.com/kamilion/customizer) are python based and I'm more interested in bash scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Dude it tells you exactly what you need to do.

Download a netinstall version of the latest Ubuntu.

During install you will need to select both "minimal or minimum" and "standard" packages.  But to be honest this system can't do much; has no GUI.  In addition to those, you need an X server which Xorg, and you need a window manager to utilize this X server basically so you can have a desktop and can have applications with graphics...the window manager you must choose for yourself but for xorg the command is probably sudo apt install xorg (it will give you a big list of things to install, but you don't need to install all of it.  You do need things like `xinit, x11-xserver-utils, xserver-xorg-video-dummy, xserver-xorg-xinput-all`
`xserver-xorg-video-all` or xserver-xorg-video-(whatever you have intel, nvidia...)
 and in combination with commands like no-install-recommends...of course nothing will work without a window manager...My suggestion install xorg in full and get it working with a window manager before you start cutting down on parts of Xorg. Use the command `startx` to start the window manager once Xorg and it are installed.

So after the standard and minimum, you have to install the stuff the enables graphics (Ubuntu only does  this in bloat fashion forcing you to use a desktop manager which necessarily has a lot of bloat between the login manager, window manager, app indicators (system tray) menu bar, other extensions...) but as I said all you need to get graphics is technically essential parts of Xorg and a complete window manager.  So what are these parts of Xorg, what do they do?
`xinit` (without it `startx` will fail, the most essential part of Xorg)
x11-xserver-utils (think about it, gives you control Xorg, what kind..investigate)

xserver-xorg-video-dummy (a placeholder so xorg will work, but without accel.)

xserver-xorg-video-all (extensions for Xorg that support accel. for all known graphics configuraitons)

xserver-xorg-xinput-all (extension for Xorg that supports all known inputs inc. game controllers)

Note: without a login manager, you will boot to a terminal where you must specify your username and password.  Once logged in, you must then type startx.  Note: there security issues with xorg, thus to mitigate always use the latest version possible and block everything from the outside from coming in with iptables which is a little complicated at first, but then everything makes sense.  ufw will not ensure you are not penetrated, only iptables can do it.  For window manager, I recommend FLWM if you want a lightweight stacking window manager or i3wm if you want tiling window manager.

Comment: These are instructions on how to do a net install. Not how to create Ubuntu Mini Remix.